# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state' Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, one-to-many, psql

I am using Postgresql and FlaskSqlalchemy . I want to create a relation such that a team can have multiple channels but a channel can only have one team(one-to-many relation). I have tried to do it by a one-to-many relationship as shown below
I have the following code in models.py

```
class Team(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "team"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    team_owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=False)
    team_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    team_logo = db.Column(db.String(120), default='default.png')
    team_description = db.Column(db.String(110), default="Welcome to My team.....")
    team_members = db.Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(JSON))
    team_members_count = db.Column(db.Integer)
    channel_list = db.relationship("Channel", backref="list", lazy=True)

class Channel(db.Model):
    channel_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    team_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("team.id"), nullable=False)
    channel_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    channel_logo = db.Column(db.String(120), default='default.jpg')
    channel_description = db.Column(db.String(110), default="Welcome to My Channel.....")
    channel_members = db.Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(JSON))
    channel_members_count = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

I am able to create a team, but when I try to create a channel every thing goes fine except the relationship part . I have tried to make the channels_list(backref='list') a list by doing

```
list = []
```

Further code is given below

```
channel = Channel(channel_name=form.channel_name.data, channel_description = 
form.channel_description.data , channel_members = {'member_id': [] , 'name' : []}, 
channel_members_count=channel_members_count, list = []
)

channel.list.append(form.channel_name.data)
db.session.add(channel)
db.session.commit()
```

NOTE: I have not added some code that is not relevant to this error eg populating channel_members to avoid wasting your time
Now when I try to create channel I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

TraceBack:[https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XHnl.png[1]
Where am I making a fault or is it even possible to store a list while having a one-to-many relationship. Also it will be best if I can have a JSON object stored while maintaing this relation. Appreciate Your Guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what "backref" means is its a "back reference" to the parent "team" that a given channel is associated with.

So if for example you had an existing team called "team_a" in the database and you wanted to create a new channel that would be associated with this "team_a". Here's how you'd do it:

```py
new_channel = Channel(channel_info)

# find team with name "team_a"

team = Team.query.filter_by(name="team_a").first()

# associate this team with the new_channel using the backref to the team
# which is called "list"

new_channel.list = team

db.session.add(new_channel)
db.session.commit()
```

`Channel.list` is not a list its a reference to the team object that the given channel is related to. So you should use it to associate a channel with a team when you're creating a new channel. That way the channel will be indexed as part of the children (or the 'many') of the parent team. Since there is a one-to-many from team -> channel.

This makes it so we can get all channels associated with the team using the "channel_list" property on a "team" object. You don't need to append to it directly on the teams object, so long as you've associated the team with the channel while creating it.

> I'd advice you to name the backref as something less confusing on the "teams" table to something like "team" or "parent_team". Like this:

```py
channel_list = db.relationship("Channel", backref="team", lazy=True)
```

Comment: Thank You But I have a question, by doing so I'll be able to associate a channel to a team separately, but can  it store the associated channel as a list or is it like after it when I do team.channel_list I get all Channels  moreover what should I replace in channel_info In first line Thanks

Comment: Yes once you do `team.channel_list` you'll get all the channels.  You can create a channel the way I did in NY answer.

Comment: Why is it new_channel = Team(channel_info) shouldnt it be  new_channel = Channel(channel_info) Im still struggling with it

Comment: I have resolved this error but when I do team.channel_list as you said I get output as: [<Channel1>,<Channel2>] Kindly guide me through this

Comment: Yes its new_channel = Channel(channel_info), that was a mistake i will correct it

Comment: The output you get is a list of channel objects associated with the given team. So you can loop through the list and get the attributes you need from them. For example, if you need to get the names of the channels under a team, you could do:


```python
channels = team.channel_list
for channel in channels:
    print(channel.channel_name)
```

Comment: Thank You very much for helping me out through this I was able to achieve what I wanted. I hope you can also guide me if I need help in future!

Comment: You're welcome feel free to mark the answer as correct, so others can find it helpful